# Pass HTTP GET by Id (Observable) values to variables on component

Tags: typescript, angular6, observable, angular-services, rxjs6

Hello guys this is my first time on a while posting here, everyone thanks for your help, but I don't know to do here.

I have a Angular+2 web app (I'm new with Angular) with one component (User) and a service (user.service.ts), I have already done my HTTP request for getUser(Id) and is returning the json correctly, on my component I need to set some variables with my service, but my variables are returning null or empty, which could be the most correct choice to do this?

I think my error could be on the .subscribe method and Observable thing.

```
//User service
getUser(id:string): Observable<User>{
        return this.http.get<User>(this.userUrl + "/"+ id);   
    }
```

```
//Component

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
    .subscribe((params:Params)=>{
      this.id = params['id'];
      this.editMode = params['id'] != null;
      this.initForm();
    });
  }
```

```
initForm(){
    let id = '';
    let company ='';
    let userNo = 0;
    let email = '';
    let firstName = '';
    let lastName = '';
    let address1 = '';
    let address2 = '';
    let city = '';
    let country = '';
    let postalCode = '';
    let mobilePhoneNumber = '';
    let homePhoneNumber = '';
    let birthday = '';
    let userType = '';
    let gender = '';

    if(this.editMode){


      this.userService.getUser(this.id).filter(x => x.id === this.id).subscribe((data:User) => { return new User(

          id = data.id,
          userNo = data.userNo,
          firstName = data.firstName,
          lastName = data.lastName,
          address1 = data.address1,
          address2 = data.address2,
          city = data.city,
          country = data.country,
          postalCode = data.postalCode,
          homePhoneNumber = data.homePhoneNumber,
          mobilePhoneNumber = data.mobilePhoneNumber,
          email = data.email,
          gender = data.gender,
          userType = data.userType

      )});


    }

    this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      'company': new FormControl(company, Validators.required), <---- company null/empty
      'userNo': new FormControl(userNo, Validators.required), <---- userNo null/empty
      'email': new FormControl(email, Validators.required), <---- email null/empty
      'firstName': new FormControl(firstName, Validators.required), <---- firstName null/empty
      'lastName': new FormControl(lastName, Validators.required), <---- lastName null/empty
      'address1': new FormControl(address1, Validators.required), <---- address1 null/empty
      'address2': new FormControl(address2, Validators.required), <---- address2 null/empty
      'city': new FormControl(city, Validators.required), <---- city null/empty
      'country': new FormControl(country, Validators.required), <---- country null/empty
      'postalCode': new FormControl(postalCode, Validators.required), <---- postalCode null/empty
      'mobilePhoneNumber': new FormControl(mobilePhoneNumber, Validators.required), <---- mobilePhoneNumber null/empty
      'homePhoneNumber': new FormControl(homePhoneNumber, Validators.required), <---- homePhoneNumber null/empty
      //'birthday': new FormControl(birthday, Validators.required), <---- birthday null/empty
      'userType': new FormControl(userType, Validators.required) <---- userType null/empty

    })



  }
```

Comment: I'm using in this way because my component is for Create/Edit user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move you `this.userForm = new FormGroup({})` logic inside your `.subscribe()` because when you are setting `this.userForm` your subscription was not yet done.

Also, your subscription is returning a new User that is not stored anywhere.

I would recommend you to create private method that takes an `User` instance and creates/ updates the form once (when no edit mode) and again when you are in edit mode and recovers the user data from your subscription.

Comment: Thanks for your help, distante, your right, I move my logic in my subscription an it works!. Also like you said I made a private methodfor both create/edit. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool! Do not forget to mark the question as correct with the green check. .